# Integrating Bootstrap in Grails 2.0.1

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I tried to integrate bootstrap in grails.  I followed official documentation.  https://github.com/groovydev/twitter-bootstrap-grails-plugin/blob/master/README.md

I added this in my BuildConfig.groovy

```
 runtime ':twitter-bootstrap:3.3.5'
```

The next step according to the documentation is to add:

> Javascript grails-app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

```
//= require bootstrap

console.log("My javascript goes here");
```

> Stylesheet grails-app/assets/javascripts/application.css:

```
/*
*= require bootstrap
*/
```

But I do not have a

> "grails-app/assets/javascripts/"

I also tried adding

> compile ":twitter-bootstrap:3.3.4"

and

> compile ":twitter-bootstrap:3.3.5"

but it also did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are not using asset-pipeline plugin. In first versions of grails2 default was resources plugin.

Comment: Could you please elaborate

Comment: Which plugin you have in your BuildConfig.groovy: "asset-pipeline" or "resources"? In your link you have info how to configure bootstrap plugin with both of them

Comment: I am using resources.  What is the differents between them.

Comment: I thought so. Thats why you do not have assets folder.  So you need to look at "Resources plugin" section

Comment: Take a look at asset pipeline docs to see differences. In general: "Asset Pipeline is intended to replace the defacto Grails equivalent (`resources-plugin`) with a more efficient, developer friendly architecture (similar to rails asset-pipeline)." But I am not sure if you can use asset pipeline with 2.0.1 version.

Comment: Is there any place where we can refer the version compactablity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107633/discussion-between-padippist-and-user3718614).